# Properties of the inverse of unit (lower) triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Is there any special properties about the inverse of a unit lower triangular matrix?

I'm trying to prove this: $$L^{-1}=I_n + N + N^2 + ... + N^{n-1}$$

where $L$ is a unit lower triangular matrix and  $L = I_n -N$

So obviously, $N$ must also be a lower triangular matrix with all zeroes on the diagonal, but I don't know how this helps.

I only getting as far as showing that $L + N = (L + N)^2 = ... = (L + N)^{n-1}$

Therefore, 
$$(n-1)I_n = N + N^2 + N^3 + ... + N^{n-1} + L + L^2 + L^3 + ... + L^{n-1} + G(N, L)$$
which is equivalent to
$$nI_n - (L + L^2 + L^3 + ... + L^{n-1} + G(N, L)) = I_n +N +N^2 + N^3 + ... + N^{n-1}$$
where $G(N, L)$ is still some function of N and L)

I'm stuck here and not sure how to show that the LHS is actually $L^{-1}$

Anyone has any suggestion? Or I'm completely off track using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that $N^n=0$ where $n\times n$ is the size of the matrix. A direct calculation then shows that $(I_n-N)(I_n+N+N^2+\cdots N^{n-1})= (I_n+N+N^2+\cdots N^{n-1})(I_n-N)=I_n$ (use distributivity).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks